# what's the difference between list '+' list and list .extend in python?

Tags: python, list, function

ex. if input "-1 1 3 -2 2", answer should be "-1 -2 1 3 2"

```
def specialsort(numbers):

    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list = numbers.split(" ")

    for number in list:
        if int(number)<0:
            list1.append(number)
        else:
            list2.append(number)
    result = list1 + list2
    return " ".join(result)
```

My question is : In this source code above, when I first used `extend` list function like `result = list1.extend(list2)`, it turned out to be an error saying `TypeError: can only join an iterable`. And when I edited it into "result = list1 + list2", it finally worked well. But I still don't understand why the one with extend function doesn't work while the other works well without problem because `list1.extend(list2)` returns same result with 'list1 + list2'.

If anyone knows about this problem, can you please explain about it? 
I would really appreciate your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
result = list1 + list2
```

makes a *new* `list` labelled `result`, whereas your previous:

```
result = list1.extend(list2)
```

extends `list1` with the contents of `list2`, so changing `list1`, but, I suspect the `result` label will end up with `None`.

Comment: omg. you are absolutely right Thank you so much!